# Chernoff bound and Polynomial Markov

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, solution-verification

I'm currently struggling the following statement;

> Show that upper bound of polynomial Markov is better than the Chernoff upper bound; that is, for given $\delta > 0,$
> $$\inf_{k = 0,1,2,...} \frac{\mathbb E [X^k]}{\delta^k} \le \inf_{\lambda \ge 0} \frac{\mathbb E [e^{\lambda X}]}{e^{\lambda \delta}}$$

I tried to use the Taylor's expansion in $e^{\lambda X}$ for both exponentials;

$$ \mathbb E [e^{\lambda X}] = \mathbb E [ 1 + \frac{\lambda X}{1!} + \frac{(\lambda X)^2}{2!} + ...]$$
$$e^{\lambda \delta} = 1 + \frac{\lambda \delta}{1!} + \frac{(\lambda \delta)^2}{2!} + ...$$

, but failed to show more things.

It would be grateful for any hint regarding this inequality (or any errors or uncertain points in the above statement).

Comment: **Recall**: For $a,b,c,d>0$, $\frac{a}b<\frac{c}d$ implies $\frac{a}b<\frac{a+c}{b+d}<\frac{c}d$.  Generalise this to infinite series and use Taylor on both exp(...).

Comment: Let $\mathbb E [e^{\lambda X}]$ the numerator, let $e^{\lambda \delta}$ be the denominator, and use the inequality that you mentioned. Is this what you meant? I believe your inequality is related to this link https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3696987/1118138

Comment: I mean if $a_n,b_n>0$ for all $n$ and $\sum a_n,\sum b_n<\infty$, then $\inf (a_n/b_n) \leq (\sum a_n)/(\sum b_n)$.

Comment: I forgot to comment here. Thank you for great help.